# Send other domain's file from expressJs

Tags: node.js, express, sendfile

I have a server (nodeJS, expressJS).
I created a route /abc in which I want to send a HTML file which is stored at Google Cloud Bucket.

I tried using res.sendFile but since it send files from the internal server, so it didn't worked for me.

My code for res.sendFile :-

```
router.get('/abc', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile("https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.html");
});
```

How to achieve this kind of scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is Google Cloud Bucket file is open or required login ?

Comment: I have kept file as public for now. And it's normal html file

Comment: Check [**Hosting a Static Website**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) might be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

use request npm : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
app.get('/abc', function(req, res) {
 req.pipe(request('https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.html')).pipe(res)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
import http;
var pipeRequest=(url,res)=>
    http.get(url, (getRes)=>{
      res.setHeader("content-type", getRes.headers['content-type']);
      getRes.pipe(res);
      }
    );

router.get('/abc', function(req, res) {
   pipeRequest("https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.html",res);
});
```